# Hottowel SPA viewmodel and jquery

Tags: jquery, viewmodel, hottowel

Below is a hottowel viewmodel.
I am trying to figure out where and how to place a jquery call

```
define(['services/logger'], function (logger) {
    var vm = {
        activate: activate,
        title: 'Applications'
    };

    return vm;

    //#region Internal Methods
    function activate() {
        logger.log('Applications', null, 'applications', true);
        return true;
    }
    //#endregion
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on where you want it to run. If you want the jquery code to execute when the viewmodel activates, then put it in the activate method. if you want it to run once, when the viewmodel is created, put it before the return statement.

Comment: Thanks John! Now I know where to place HT SPA questions ;) --LastTribunal.

Answer (score 3):

What I want to know is "why do you want jQuery in your ViewModel?" jQuery is for DOM manipulation. Well we have KO to that for us with binding. We shouldn't need jQuery. The use of jQuery in a ViewModel is usually (not always) a code smell. My rule of thumb is "if I'm using jQuery, I'm doing it wrong."

Comment: Ward, thanks, I am still wrapping my brain around all this MVVM, SPA, Durandal Hottowel stuff.  Great advice, I will keep in mind.

Comment: There are exceptions, as Ward says.  try to avoid it, but sometimes it just happens, and Im ok with that.

Comment: To use some 3rd party UI libs/widgets, jQuery is often necessary to enable them. We can put jquery specific code directly on the view (html) inside a script tag, but to leverage debugging on visual studio, I prefer put JS code on viewAttached inside the viewmodel. Maybe a code smell or not, but like @JohnPapa says, sometimes it just happens.

Comment: We all live with smells. But when you have one hand on the keyboard and the other pinching your nose ... it's time to ask yourself if you truly understand that **data binding obviates the need for jQuery DOM manipulation in a VM**. When you find yourself writing jQuery in the VM, think about moving that out to a custom KO binding where it belongs. You can debug your custom bindings as easily as a VM. Binding logic is where DOM manipulation belongs.

Comment: viewAttached: viewAttached!